# I need a way to prevent adding repeat information in database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

How can I prevent adding repeat information in my database (SQL Server) in the Categories table for the CategoryName column?

```
Private Sub ButtonSave_Click() Handles ButtonSave.Click

    If IsDataComplete() = False Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    sql = "INSERT INTO Categories(CategoryName) VALUES(@name)"

    command.Parameters.Clear()
    command.CommandText = sql
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", TextName.Text)

    Dim result As Integer = command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    If result = -1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("เกิดข้อผิดพลาดไม่สามารถเพิ่มข้อมูลได้")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("บันทึกข้อมูล")
        ButtonAdd.PerformClick()
    End If

End Sub
```

(English is not my first language.)

Comment: Set an UNIQUE index on the CategoryName field and you will not be able to insert two categories with the same name. Or look at IF EXIST or MERGE statements

Comment: Incidentally, the parameter name needs to be `"@name"`, not just `"name"`. Also, just so you know, AddWithValue is not always a good method to use: [AddWithValue is Evil](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/), [AddWithValue is evil!](http://chrisrickard.blogspot.com/2007/06/addwithvalue-is-evil.html), and [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).